# Не работает фрагмент JavaScript кода - Шапка при скролле экрана

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, header

Суть проблемы. Есть сайт. На сайте есть шапка которая при скролле экрана прилипает к верхней части экрана. Задача - сделать так что бы с обычного, десктопного ПК всё осталось так как есть, а с мобильной версии, что бы не прилипало, и уезжало вверх со всем остальным.

Код, который за это должен по идее отвечать (если верить комментарию):

```
// trigger fixed header only for large screens
$.onMediaQuery('(min-width: 1000px)', {
    valid: function() {
        $(window).load(function(){
        $(".fixed-header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });

        });
    }
});
```

Сам сайт - сихем.рф

Понимаю, что в идеале надо почитать учебники, но этот вопрос уж очень срочный. Я не прошу всё сделать за меня, подскажите направление поиска решения.

Comment: Вы используете **jquery**? Тогда что за функция `onMediaQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблема в onMediaQuery?

Вот например можно сделать так:

```
$(function () {
    // если ширина экрана меньше 1000px, в этом случае аналог $(window).width() < 1000
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
        $(".fixed-header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    }
});
```

Если хотите реакцию на изменение размера окна нужно использовать подписаться на событие `resize`, вот так:

```
function resize() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)").matches) {
        $(".fixed-header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
})
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61vbL57o/3/)